# Looping 2D ArrayList in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dynamic

Below data is returned from Servlet to JSP.

```
List< List < String > > formData = new ArrayList< List< String > >();
```

formData has `[[A, D], [, E], [B], [], [], [C]]`

I am unable to loop through above list using javascript in jsp.

I tried assigning formdata to a variable and accessed it using index as below

In JSP:

```
var myData = "${formData}";

var i=0;

var j=0;

alert(myData[i][j])
```

alert shows the value as undefined.

Please let me know how to loop through formData list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that printing the toString of a bidiminsional collection of strings from jsp in the javascript source is a good idea. That's one of the things transport/representational languages have been created for. For this reason, I would suggest to print the JSON representation of that bidimensional collection.
What you need in the JavaScript source code, a bidimensional array of String is:

```
[["A", "D"], [, "E"], ["B"], [], [], ["C"]]
```

Notice the double quotes, those are important, without those, the generated javascript array is a bidimensional array of variables (A, D, E, B, C).

For example, using Gson (google json library), in Java I would create 
formData like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String toPrintInTheJSP = gson.toJson(<your Java bidimensional collection of strings here>);
```

In the JSP I would output:

```
var myData = ${formData}; //without the double quotes
var i=0, j=0;
alert(myData[i][j])
```

If you need to cycle through the collection in JSP (that means while generating the markup (I quote, "I tried assigning formdata to a variable and accessed it using index as below
In JSP: [...]") ), there are different methods to do that, for example a scriptlet or JSTL.

I'm not really sure about what you have to do, the terminology you used in your question is a little bit imprecise. I think you need to cycle in JavaScript on a bidimensional array written by a JSP.

If you have to cycle through the array in JavaScript, you need a nested loop, like this:

```
    var myData = [["A", "D"], [, "E"], ["B"], [], [], ["C"]];
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < myData[i].length; j++){
            alert(myData[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets around `${formdata}`in your JSP:

```
var myData = ${formData};

var i=0;

var j=0;

alert( myData[i][j] ) ;
```

Your were assigning a string to `myData`. To loop through the array, you either need to parse that string using `JSON.parse()` or assign it as an array directly as shown above.

Comment: when i tried removing the quotes around ${formData}, alert message is not shown. In the same line, it shows a missing semicolon error

Comment: @Surabhi I put up a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4u8xL/). If your output is similar for `${formdata}`, this should work.

Comment: I tried removing the quotes from the string and assigning it to new variable var newData =  myData.substring(1, myData.length-1); but alert of newData[0][0] didnt work

Comment: @Surabhi Can you modify my fiddle in such a way, that I can see, what data arrives at the client's browser?

Comment: I was unble to edit your fiddle. I have create one here [link]http://jsfiddle.net/Surabhi_sn/whZrR/. Basically I have introduced double quotes and converted myData to String. Please let me know how to convert String to array in Javascript. Thanks

Comment: @Surabhi Your output isn't exactly valid JSON. (1) The Strings inside should be enclosed using `"` and (2) the empty element before `'E'` is not valid. Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9ZTa/), I corrected the errors and it works. So maybe you can adjust your output accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Sirko for your help. I managed to convert the List<List> to 2D array. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/Surabhi_sn/whZrR/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData = "${formData}";
```

Transforms to:

```
var myData = "[[A, D], [, E], [B], [], [], [C]]";
```

In javascript, to create an array, you have to use:

```
var myData = [[A, D], [, E], [B], [], [], [C]];
```

Comment: when i tried removing the quotes around ${formData}, alert message is not shown for myData[0][0]. In the same line, it shows a missing semicolon error